# Show/Hide List Items Based on Check Boxes (Filtering)

Tags: jquery, html, filter

I've got ~150 list items each with data attributes I want to filter by. For starters I want to just have a single checkbox that looks at one data attribute and can show only the list items associated with it.

I'm REALLY lost past that as I'm fairly new still. Can't seem to find anything out there, maybe I'm searching for the wrong terms.

```
<div class="container">
    <input name="Fluid Width" type="checkbox"><span>Fluid</span>
</div>
<ul id="myList">
<li data-width-type='Fixed Width' data-carousel='No' data-columns='3'>Adventure</li>
<li data-width-type='Fixed Width' data-carousel='No' data-columns='3'>Antiques</li>
<li data-width-type='Fluid Width' data-carousel='No' data-columns='3'>ArtFraming</li>
<li data-width-type='Fluid Width' data-carousel='No' data-columns='3'>ArtsCrafts</li>
<li data-width-type='Fluid Width' data-carousel='No' data-columns='3'>Automotive</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
var list = $('#myList')

$('.container').on('change','.filter',function() {

});
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vEzdC/

Tips on what I should be searching for or trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.container input:checkbox').on('change',function() {
           $("#myList [data-width-type!='"+this.name+"']").toggle();
    });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/vEzdC/6/

Comment: It could be I'm not understanding this quite correctly, but I think maybe I didn't explain it right the first time. When I check the box I'm trying to hide anything that doesn't have "Fluid Width" as the data-width-type attribute. We're getting somewhere though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` this way:

```
$(function(){
   $('.container').on('change',function() {
        var $in=$("input:checkbox",this);
        $("#myList li").filter(function(index){
        return !($(this).data("width-type") == $in.attr("name"));
        }).toggle();
    });
});
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vEzdC/5/)